# SQL query UNION to another tables to select data

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have the following query....

```
SELECT t1.ProductID, t2.Name as [Product Type], t3.Name as [Product Category], 
t4.Name as [Product Provider]
From  tblProducts t1 
Inner Join tblReferences t2 on t1.ProductType = t2.ID 
Inner Join tblReferences t3 on t1.ProductCategory = t3.ID 
Inner Join tblReferences t4 on t1.ProductProvider = t4.ID
```

I know this is not the prettiest query, but it does the job, and most likely won't be edited once its finalized. Now I'm trying to do an INNER JOIN with another Table and here's where the issue comes...

So I'm trying to to PULL data from another table (tblProductSeller), however I'd need it to show as [Product Provider]

so to add on the the previous SELECT statement...

```
     SELECT t1.ProductID, t2.Name as [Product Type], t3.Name as [Product Category], 
t4.Name as [Product Provider], 

t6.SellerName as [Product Provider] <---new line -
```

however this displays it as a new column, I'm trying to display it in the same column as

```
t4.Name as [Product Provider]
```

the rest of the query I tried is

```
Inner Join tblReferences t2 on t1.ProductType = t2.ID 
Inner Join tblReferences t3 on t1.ProductCategory = t3.ID 
Inner Join tblReferences t4 on t1.ProductProvider = t4.ID
Inner Join tblProductSeller t6 on t1.ProductProvider = t6.ID
```

Is something like that even possible - do I have to do an UNION?

EDIT . To keep it short I'll abandon most of the fields with the exception fo the one I'm having an issue with.

```
 TblProducts
 ProductID          ProviderID          
 17                 16
 18                 20
 19                 24

 tblReferences
 ID                 Name
 16                 Microsoft
 20                 ADP

 tblProductSeller 
 ID                 ProductProvider
 24                 Apple
```

TblReferences has the names of some standard Sellers, however, I need to be able to reference tblProductSeller, since alot of the providers will be added in there. Basically that's the place where they'll be added. All my data is stored in tblProducts.

My entire goal is to be able to populate a DataGridView, however, not have any ID's but rather be able to reference both tblReferences, and tblProductSeller.

So my end result would look like

> ```
> ProductID      Contact Provider
>  16                Microsoft
>  20                ADP
>  24                Apple
> ```

Comment: If I can provide any more info please let me know.

Comment: Display in the same column means waht? concating it? You can do `(t4.Name + '  ' + t6.SellerName) as [Product Provider]`

Comment: @mihil not concatenate. In tblProducts I have integer (ID's) saved for Product Provider. I'm trying to select Contact Provider TEXT from tblReferences, and tblProductSeller. Not all ID's can be references in tblReferences since some of the Product Providers are in tblProductSeller, so I need it to reference both for the actually TEXT values instead of ID's.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would better explain what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - see edit. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the use case as to which tables are needed the statements would need to be adjusted below, but just to get your wheels turning... here is an example.

```
    SELECT  t1.ProductID, 
            t2.Name as [Product Type], 
            t3.Name as [Product Category], 
            t4.Name as [Product Provider]
    From  tblProducts t1 
    Inner Join tblReferences t2 
    on t1.ProductType = t2.ID 
    Inner Join tblReferences t3 
    on t1.ProductCategory = t3.ID 
    Inner Join tblReferences t4 
    on t1.ProductProvider = t4.ID 
UNION 
    Select  t1.ProductID, 
            t2.Name as [Product Type], 
            t3.Name as [Product Category], 
            t6.Name as [Product Provider]
    From  tblProducts t1 
    Inner Join tblReferences t2 
    on t1.ProductType = t2.ID 
    Inner Join tblReferences t3 
    on t1.ProductCategory = t3.ID  
    Inner Join tblProductSeller t6 
    on t1.ProductProvider = t6.ID
```

Comment: No problem, glad I can help.

Comment: Seems like a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE()` would be a lot easier...  Of course, if you need an extra row when `t4.Name` differs from `t6.SellerName` then a `UNION` is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution, as described by ebyrob:

```
SELECT  t1.ProductID, 
        t2.Name as [Product Type], 
        t3.Name as [Product Category], 
        IsNull(t4.Name, t6.Name) as [Product Provider]
From  tblProducts t1 
Inner Join tblReferences t2 on t1.ProductType = t2.ID 
Inner Join tblReferences t3 on t1.ProductCategory = t3.ID 
LEFT Join tblReferences t4 on t1.ProductProvider = t4.ID
LEFT Join tblProductSeller t6 on t1.ProductProvider = t6.ID;
```

What this will do is show the `Name` from `tblReferences` if there is one, otherwise it will show the `Name` from `tblProductSeller`. You could reorder those depending upon your requirements. You may also wish to add a predicate like

`WHERE t4.ID IS NOT NULL OR t6.ID IS NOT NULL`

This will avoid returning multiple rows in the situation where there is a match in both `tblReferences` and `tblProductSeller`.

Comment: That's the issue I'm having. Some ID's are both in tblReferences and tblProductSeller. Now for some of them I need pulled up from tblReferences and some from tblProductSeller.

Comment: How do you know which one you need to get from each table? @Bobski

Comment: I kinda fixed the issue by changing the ID's in tblProductSeller to a different number so when i save it and reference it in my query against the tblReference, it doesn't find it

Comment: basically a number that will never come up in tblReferences